# The analog of java.util.Calendar in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, java-calendar

I need to do calculations like:

- Given Unix time, tell the day of week.
- Add given number of seconds to the known date, and get the new date.
- Get the time (duration) difference between the two dates.

Ideally it should figure out for me the number of working days between the two Unix times but I understand that this may be too much.

When using Java, I would use java.util.Calendar for all these tasks. Which tools should be used in Ionic framework to get the same functionality? I tried to google "calendar ionic" but all results point to the Calendar GUI component that is not relevant for my task.

Comment: what about https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#advanced-datetime-validation-and-manipulation ?

Comment: or simply use the javascript date object

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes in Java such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I need to develop for Ionic now.